# Authorize.Net AIM/SIM APIs and Simple Checkout Officially Deprecated

Tags: .net, vb.net, authorize.net, authorize.net-aim

From AuthNet's site:

> Our legacy Advanced Integration Method (AIM) and Server Integration
>   Method (SIM) APIs, as well as our Simple Checkout option, are now
>   officially deprecated, meaning we will no longer provide any updates
>   to these APIs.

We have a desktop app written in vb years ago which is using AuthNet, how do I determine if this app is using AIM or SIM? Code below:-

```
Private Sub DoRefund()
    Try

        Authorizer.Add("x_login", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AuthNetID").ToString)
        Authorizer.Add("x_tran_key", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AuthNetKey").ToString)
        Authorizer.Add("x_type", "CREDIT")
        Authorizer.Add("x_trans_id", HoldTransID)
        Authorizer.Add("x_duplicate_window", "1")

        Dim decTempTotal As Decimal = decTotValue

        If Not Authorizer.AuthorizePayment(HoldCC, HoldExpMo + "/" + HoldExpYr, HoldCCCID, decTotValue.ToString) Then
            ' insert RefundBatchExceptions record.
            ' logging exception
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ListBox1.Items.Add("Refund successful for Card Order/Credit Card: " + HoldCorderID + "/" + HoldCC + " for " + Format(decTotValue, "C"))
        ListBox1.Refresh()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
```

with the changes in AuthNet, do I need to change something in this app?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the AIM API. You can tell because of two factors:

1. `x_login` and other `x_*` fields which typical of AIM and not their newer XML/JSON APIs
2. This code issues a refund which is not available in SIM